# Parse a string into object?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Would it be possible to parse a string as follows… `{"Key": "Value"}` back into a object? When I ever I try to parse it, I receive errors. I've been trying to use `json.parse`, but that does not work either.

This is what i have mapped out, but for this format it fails.

```js
// Creating a list of objects, while mapping properties of an object
let obj = "{
  "key": "3"
}";
let objList = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => Object.fromEntries(new Map([
  [key, value]
])));
```

Comment: hmm.. u mean like `JSON.parse("{'key':'value'}")`?

Comment: _"I've been trying to use `json.parse`, but that does not work either."_ - can you post your attempts at that approach, along with issues you've had, since that would be the normal thing to do.

Comment: That's not a string, that's already an object.

Comment: Your code doesn't include the string you mentioned. It's really unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: In your example only the values must be parsed, that's what you're looking for ?

Comment: @DaveNewton if that's an object, then I dont get why it does not work in the code snippet?

Comment: @Fraction yes, basically I want the keys and values from this string

Comment: @MauricioSipmann That would work if it were in that format, but its actually "{"key":"value"}"

Comment: That by itself isn't valid syntax.  Do you mean you have a string that contains `{"key":"value"}` or do you have a string that contains `"{"key":"value"}"`.  You can't directly put `"{"key":"value"}"` in your source, as that's not valid, but you _could_ have a string that contains that value.  Can you edit your question to show precisely what you're working with?

Comment: @bitznbytez I updated my answer in reply of your edited question.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I actually am getting that string returned from an api call in that exact format. Any suggestions? Something to be addressed from the server side maybe?

Comment: If the server is returning exactly `{"key": "3"}` it is enough JSON.parse.

Comment: @bitznbytez If you execute your code you'll get a `SyntaxError`, you're sure that your json is not like: `"{  \"key\": \"3\"}"` ?

Comment: In what format (I specified two)? Using `"` inside the string around keys/values and is also surrounded by `"`?  If so, then yes - this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where the solution is to go ask (or fix if it's yours) the server response to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
let obj = "{
  "key": "3"
}";
```

This is incorrect: if you want to write a [multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript), you have to put a `\` at the end of the line:

```
let obj = "{\
    "key": "3"\
}";
```

But there is another error: you have to escape the `"`:

```
let obj ="{\
    \"key\": \"3\"\
}";
```

You could use `'` for enclosing string instead of `"` so you don't need the escape:

```
let obj = '{\
    "key": "3"\
}';
```

Anyway this is a little string, you could write it in one line:

```
let obj = '{"key": "3"}';
```

Now you can use JSON.parse.

```js
let obj = '{"key": "3"}';
console.log( JSON.parse(obj) );
```